# How to use jquery selector to search through a list

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, coffeescript

I am trying to implement a search using jQuery.

I will allow the user to enter a search string for example 'zzz', and I want to loop through the 'ul lists' to select only the 'li's with the value containing the search string.

For example, if zzz is the search string, i would only want to select the 2nd 'li' where the value is 'zzzzaaa'

```
<ul class="inputs-list"><li>
   <label class="user">
      <input type="checkbox" value="abcd" name="optionsCheckboxes">
      <img style="height: 30px;" src="http://boom.dailymus.es/v1/users/profile/502245329/square">
      <span>abcdefg</span>
   </label>
</li>

<li>
  <label class="user">
    <input type="checkbox" value="zzzzaaaa" name="optionsCheckboxes">
    <img style="height: 30px;" src="http://boom.dailymus.es/v1/users/profile/547205429/square">
    <span>zzzzz</span>
  </label>
</li>
```

I tried with the following code but with no avail

```
$.each @inputs_list.find('li'), (index, user) ->
  if user.find('input')[value *='#{searchString}']
     console.log('selected', user)
```

How can I modify my code to make the search work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following takes all checkboxes that are descendants of ".inputs-list", uses the [`.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce the set to those that contain the search string in their value property, and then uses the [`.closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the li elements that the matching inputs belong to:

```
var searchString = "zzz"; // obviously you'd get this from the user somehow

searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
var matchingLIs = $("ul.inputs-list :checkbox").filter(function(){
                    return this.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) != -1;
                  }).closest("li");
```

You don't make it clear what you actually want to do to/with the matching li elements, but say you wanted to hide all the ones that don't match you could do this:

```
$("ul.inputs-list > li").hide();
$("ul.inputs-list :checkbox").filter(function(i){
    return this.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) != -1;
}).closest("li").show();
```

Comment: thanks for the solution! I think this works well for me. =) I need the search to be case insensitive. I am thinking of making the search string and the value all to lowercases before comparing. But is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I intended to give you a case insensitive solution, especially after I commented on that very point on another answer, but then I forgot by the time I actually typed up my suggestion. I'll update my answer to do it with `.toLowerCase()`, but you could also use a case-insensitive regex test (but that's a bit more hassle because you have to create a regex from what the user entered which means you have to worry about escaping any characters that they entered which have special meaning in a regular expression).

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at `:contains` for jQuery

```
$("div:contains('John')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

```
$('.inputs-list').find("li:contains('" + searchString + "')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```

Something like that is what I would try...

Comment: couldn't that be avoided by translating everything to lower or uppercase?

Answer (score 1):

#### Hiding/Showing with jQuery

Initially, I'd do something like this:

```
// Real-time filtering, when the key is released
$("#terms").on("keyup", function(e){

  // Hide all list items, get those that match, show them
  $(".inputs-list li").hide().filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().match( new RegExp( e.target.value ) );
  }).show();

});
```

Depending on the size of your list, I suspect there may be a flash in which no elements will be visible. I'm currently working on a better approach.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/uzotiy/edit#javascript,html

#### Hiding/Showing with CSS

Manipulating elements with CSS will be much faster and more efficient than jQuery. As such, this method merely adds and removes a "highlight" class. The class rules should be responsible for highlighting or setting the `display` of matched elements:

```
$("#terms").on("keyup", function(e){
  $(".inputs-list li")
    .removeClass("highlight")
    .filter(":contains(" + e.target.value + ")")
      .addClass("highlight");
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/uzotiy/2/edit#source

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Here class search is the search text box.

```
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $(".search").keyup(function()
            {
                var key=this.value;

                if(key.length>2)
                {
                    $(".user").each(function()
                    {
                        $this=$(this).find("input:first");
                        var val=$this.val();
                        var res = val.indexOf(key);


                        if(res!=-1)
                        {

                            $this.attr("checked","checked");
                        } 
                        else
                        {            
                            $this.removeAttr("checked");
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
        });
```